# Typescript's equivalent of Java's enum (or C#'s struct)

Tags: typescript, enums

I need to create an enum in Typescript. However, you can only use an integer based enum like with C# for example. Still C# has it's struct to do non-integer related things. This doesn't seem to be implemented within TypeScript. Do I need to "work around" or is there something implemented?

What I try to achieve is an equivalent in TypeScript to this Java code:

```
public enum Something { 

 PENNY("PENNY"), NICKLE("NICKLE"); 

 private String value; 

 private Something (String value) { 
  this.value = value; 
 } 

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking at this question i found that since typescript 2.4 they already have a String Enums support. It's similar to java's enum and very intuitive to use.

[From the release notes for TypeScript 2.4:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html)

> #### String Enums
>
> TypeScript 2.4 now allows enum members to contain string initializers.

```
enum Colors {
    Red = "RED",
    Green = "GREEN",
    Blue = "BLUE", }
```

> The caveat is that string-initialized enums can’t be reverse-mapped to get the original enum member name. In other words, you can’t write Colors["RED"] to get the string "Red".

Comment: I wonder what the rules are on re-accepting answers when the new answer uses features and technology not available at the time of asking.

Answer (score 5):

Now is typescript@3.5.2, but enum like java or c# - absent.
So i wrote some workaround.

```js
/**
 * Decorator for Enum.
 * @param {string} idPropertyName - property name to find enum value by property value. Usage in valueOf method
 * @return constructor of enum type
 */
export function Enum<T = any>(idPropertyName?: keyof T) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line
    return function <T extends (Function & EnumClass)>(target: T): T {
        const store: EnumStore = {
            name: target.prototype.constructor.name,
            enumMap: {},
            enumMapByName: {},
            enumValues: [],
            idPropertyName: idPropertyName
        };
        // Lookup static fields
        for (const fieldName of Object.keys(target)) {
            const value: any = (target as any)[fieldName];
            // Check static field: to be instance of enum type
            if (value instanceof target) {
                const enumItem: Enumerable = value;
                let id = fieldName;
                if (idPropertyName) {
                    id = (value as any)[idPropertyName];
                    if (typeof id !== "string" && typeof id !== "number") {
                        const enumName = store.name;
                        throw new Error(`The value of the ${idPropertyName} property in the enumeration element ${enumName}.${fieldName} is not a string or a number: ${id}`);
                    }
                }
                if (store.enumMap[id]) {
                    const enumName = store.name;
                    throw new Error(`An element with the identifier ${id}: ${enumName}.${store.enumMap[id].enumName} already exists in the enumeration ${enumName}`);
                }
                store.enumMap[id] = enumItem;
                store.enumMapByName[fieldName] = enumItem;
                store.enumValues.push(enumItem);
                enumItem.__enumName__ = fieldName;
                Object.freeze(enumItem);
            }
        }
        target.__store__ = store;
        Object.freeze(target.__store__);
        Object.freeze(target);
        return target;
    };
}

/** Key->Value type */
export type EnumMap = {[key: string]: Enumerable};

/** Type for Meta-Data of Enum */
export type EnumClass = {
    __store__: EnumStore
};

/** Store Type. Keep meta data for enum */
export type EnumStore = {
    name: string,
    enumMap: EnumMap,
    enumMapByName: EnumMap,
    enumValues: Enumerable[],
    idPropertyName?: any
};

/** Enum Item Type */
export type EnumItemType = {
    __enumName__: string;
};

/** Interface for IDE: autocomplete syntax and keywords */
export interface IStaticEnum<T> extends EnumClass {

    new(): {enumName: string};

    values(): ReadonlyArray<T>;

    valueOf(id: string | number): T;

    valueByName(name: string): T;
}

/** Base class for enum type */
export class Enumerable implements EnumItemType {
    // tslint:disable:variable-name
    // stub. need for type safety
    static readonly __store__ = {} as EnumStore;
    // Initialize inside @Enum decorator
    __enumName__ = "";
    // tslint:enable:variable-name

    constructor() {
    }

    /**
     * Get all elements of enum
     * @return {ReadonlyArray<T>} all elements of enum
     */
    static values(): ReadonlyArray<any> {
        return this.__store__.enumValues;
    }

    /**
     * Lookup enum item by id
     * @param {string | number} id - value for lookup
     * @return enum item by id
     */
    static valueOf(id: string | number): any {
        const value = this.__store__.enumMap[id];
        if (!value) {
            throw new Error(`The element with ${id} identifier does not exist in the $ {clazz.name} enumeration`);
        }
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Lookup enum item by enum name
     * @param {string} name - enum name
     * @return item by enum name
     */
    static valueByName(name: string): any {
        const value = this.__store__.enumMapByName[name];
        if (!value) {
            throw new Error(`The element with ${name} name does not exist in the ${this.__store__.name} enumeration`);
        }
        return value;
    }

    /** Get enum name */
    get enumName(): string {
        return this.__enumName__;
    }

    /** Get enum id value or enum name */
    toString(): string {
        const clazz = this.topClass;
        if (clazz.__store__.idPropertyName) {
            const self = this as any;
            return self[clazz.__store__.idPropertyName];
        }
        return this.enumName;
    }

    private get topClass(): EnumClass {
        return this.constructor as any;
    }
}

/** 'Casting' method to make correct Enum Type */
export function EnumType<T>(): IStaticEnum<T> {
    return (<IStaticEnum<T>> Enumerable);
}
```

Now, it's easy to use

```js
// node-module
// import {Enum, EnumType} from "ts-jenum";

@Enum("value")
class Something extends EnumType<Something>() {

    static readonly PENNY = new Something("Penny");
    static readonly NICKLE = new Something("Nickle");

    constructor(readonly value: string) {
        super();
    }
}

// Usage example
console.log("" + Something.PENNY);              // Penny
console.log("" + Something.NICKLE);             // Nickle
console.log(Something.values());                // [Something.PENNY, Something.NICKLE]
console.log(Something.valueByName("PENNY"));    // Something.PENNY
console.log(Something.PENNY.enumName);          // PENNY
```

All things above are type safety.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't give explicit string values (only numbers), TypeScript enums can be referred to by both their index and their names. You can access their names by passing the number back to the enum, like so:

```
enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }

console.info(Direction[Direction.Up]); // "Up"
```

Alternatively, use a Map:

```
const directionText = new Map([
  [Direction.Up, 'UP'],
  // ...
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an enum as simple as this. It works the same way as in Java or in C#.

```
export enum ControlType {
  INPUT,
  SELECT,
  DATEPICKER
}


console.log(ControlType.INPUT); // returns 0
console.log(ControlType[ControlType.INPUT]); // returns INPUT
```

You can also add additional information but as you noticed, only with type number.

```
export enum ControlType {
  INPUT = 3,
  SELECT = 6,
  DATEPICKER = "abc".length // computed member
}

console.log(ControlType.INPUT); // returns 3
```

Things get harder when you want to add other members that are not of type number but there is a work-around. You must set the type to `<any>`

```
export enum ControlType {
  INPUT = <any>'input',
  SELECT = <any>'select',
  DATEPICKER = <any>'date-picker'
}

console.log(ControlType.INPUT); // returns 'input'
```

The downside here is that you can only match these values with other variables of type `any`. e.g. in the case of;

```
(ControlType.INPUT === myVar) {..}
```

myVar must be declared as `myVar: any = 'input';` even if it's a string.